# Determine which Celery workers are consuming jobs and telling them to stop

Tags: multithreading, celery, django-celery

**Scenario:**  How to I gracefully tell a worker to stop accepting new jobs and identify when they are finished processing the current jobs as to shut them down as workers are coming online.

Details (Feel free to correct any of my assumptions):

Here is snippet of my current queue.

[image: Queues]

As you can see I have 2 exchange queues for the workers (I believe this is the *.pidbox), 2 queues representing celeryev on each host (yes I know I only need one), and one default celery queue.  Clearly I have 90+ jobs in this queue.

**(Side Question) Where do you go to find the worker consuming the job from the Management console?** I know I can look at djcelery and figure that out.

[image: DJCelery Jobs]

So.. I know there are jobs running on each host - I can't shut celery off those machines as it will kill the jobs running (and any pending?).

**How do I stop any further processing of new jobs while allowing those jobs still running to complete?** I know that on each host I can stop celery but that will kill any current jobs running as well.  I want to say to the 22 jobs in the hopper to **halt**.

Thanks!!